# Can I see the complete request URL (including the query string) for Google Cloud Function requests?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging

I'm using Google Cloud Functions and requests contain a query string `https://europe-west1-foobar.cloudfunctions.net/foobar?bar=baq`

Is it possible for me to retrieve `bar=baq` from the Google Cloud logs? If so, how?

Comment: I searched, I tested, I activated the audit logs,.... I haven't found. I guess it's not a feature out of box

Comment: To bad - thanks for looking though

Answer (score 0):

For the moment there's no such feature - just as [guillaume blaquiere wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67335085/can-i-see-the-complete-request-url-including-the-query-string-for-google-cloud#comment119061499_67335085).

However you can file a feature request on [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com). Provide as much detailes on how you'd like this feature to work, maybe some examples - that will improve the chance of it being implemented.